# Create np.array filled with zero arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to initialize an "empty" array with each elements containing `t_list` a 8x8 np.zeros array :

`t_list = np.zeros((8,8), dtype=np.float32)`

I would now want to have a `np.array` with multiple t_list at each indexes:

`result = np.array((t_list, t_list, ...., tlist))`

I would like to be able to control the number of time `t_list` is in `result`.

I know that I could use list instead of arrays. The problem is, I put this in a numba njit function so I need to precise everything.

The aim is then to change each values in a double `for` loop.

Comment: why not give `np.zeroes` another dimension? like `result = np.zeros((5,8,8), dtype=np.float32)`

Comment: It perfectly works! Thanks a lot

Comment: Cool! making it a proper answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shape` param of [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) can be a tuple of ints of any length, so you can create an `ndarray` with multiple dimensions.

e.g.:

```py
n = 5 # or any other number that you want
result = np.zeros((n,8,8), dtype=np.float32)
```